# Can this modified Gaussian integral be calculated analytically?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

In my research, I encounter this modified Gaussian integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\,\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-bx}}{2\sqrt{x^2-bx}}\exp\left[-a^2(x-x_0)^2+i\left(cx-d\sqrt{x^2-bx}\right)\right],$$
where the parameters $a,\ b,\ c, d$ are all real. I want to know whether this integral can be calculated analytically, such as using contour integration.   Could anyone kindly help me?

Comment: What is $\sqrt{x^2-bx}$ when $b\ne0$ and $x$ is in $(0,b)$?

Comment: @Did Despite $\sqrt{x^2-bx}$ is multivalued as x is in $(0,b)$, only one branch $i\sqrt{bx-x^2}$ need to be concerned in my research.